# Finding general form of Taylor polynomial for function $f(x)=e^{x}\sin(x)$

Tags: calculus, polynomials, taylor-expansion

I am trying to find the general form the Taylor polynomial of the function $f(x)=e^{x}\sin(x)$.

I have calculated the derivatives up to $5$:

$$\begin{align}
f^{(1)}(x)&=e^{x}\cos(x) + e^{x} \sin(x)\\
f^{(2)}(x)&= 2e^{x}\cos(x)= e^{x}(\sin(x)+ \cos(x)) + e^{x}(\cos(x)- \sin(x))\\
f^{(3)}(x)&=2e^{x}\cos(x) -2e^{x} \sin(x)\\
f^{(4)}(x)&=-4e^{x}\sin(x)\\
f^{(5)}(x)&=-4e^{x}\cos(x) -4e^{x} \sin(x)\\
\end{align}$$

Based on the formula for computing Taylor polynomials:

$P_{n}(x)=f(a)+\frac{f^{1} (a)}{1!}(x-a)+\frac{f^{2} (a)}{2!}(x-a)^{2}+...
+\frac{f^{n} (a)}{n!}(x-a)^{n}$

I have computed, up to the 5th derivative, the Taylor polynomial for $f(x)=e^{x}\sin(x)$ where $a=0$:

$=  x+x^2+\frac{x^{3}}{3}-\frac{x^{5}}{30}$

Now, I am having a little issue coming up with a general equation to this Taylor polynomial. I cannot seem to see the overarching patterns that'll lead to the generalized form. Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: An idea might be to use Euler's formula $ e^{i x } = \cos x + i \sin x$ - substituting in, one gets  
$$f(x) = {\rm Im}\, e^{(1+i)x} .$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Call the original function $f^{(0)}(x)$. You have shown that $f^{(4)}(x)=-4f^{(0)}(x)$. So in general $f^{(4n+k)}(x)=(-4)^n f^{(k)}(x)$.

For example we can conclude that if $m=4n$, then $f^{(m)}(0)=0$. If $m=4n+1$ then $f^{(m)}(0)=(-4)^n$. There are only two more congruence classes to deal with.

Comment: Ahh, yes, I do see the relationship you are referring to,  but I am having trouble seeing the other two congruence classes. Is one dealing with the changing sign?

Comment: For $m=4n+2$, the $m$-th derivative at $0$ is $2(-4)^n$. The same is true for $m=4n+3$.  Now divide by the appropriate factorial to get the coefficient of $x^m$ for each of the four cases $m=4n$, $4n+1$, $4n+2$, $4n+3$.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am sorry to say that I am still struggling coming up with a final answer for the general nth term. Although the answer is probably quite clear, I'm having a little trouble with this. Could you possibly write out and explain the complete nth general term to help in my understanding?

Comment: I gave (half in the answer, half in a later comment) explicit formulas for $f^{(m)}(0)$ for $m=4n$, $m=4n+1$, $m=4n+2$, and $m=4n+3$. Dividing by $m!$ gives you $a_m$, where $f(x)=\sum_0^\infty a_m x^m$. This is a *complete* description of all the coefficients. Maybe you want a "single formula" and not a cases formula.  I can produce such a formula, fooling around with powers of $i$, or of $-1$ using the floor function, or values of trig functions at special angles. The result will be less directly informative than the cases formula.